# Make computations in a child component after axios requests in a parent component

Tags: vue.js

Here is my problem : I have a parent component `Edit` that makes several `axios` requests, the results of these requests are passed down to a child component (Menu in my example).

```html
    <template>
    <div>
        <p>
            Order Id : {{ this.$route.params.id }}
        </p>

        <head-fields :menu="menu"></head-fields>

        <div>
            <b-tabs content-class="mt-3">
                <b-tab title="Menu" active>
                    <Menu :menuItems="items" :nutritionalValues="nutritionalValues"></Menu>
                </b-tab>
                <b-tab title="Specifications">
                    <specifications :specifications="specifications">
                    </specifications>
                </b-tab>
                <b-tab title="Redundancies"><p>I'm the redundancies tab!</p></b-tab>
            </b-tabs>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


    <script>
        import HeadFields from "./HeadFields";
        import Menu from "./Menu";
        import Specifications from "./Specifications";

        export default {
            name: "Edit",
            components: {HeadFields, Menu, Specifications},
            data(){
                return{
                    menu: {},
                    loaded: false,
                    items: {},
                    nutritionalValues: {},
                    specifications: {},
                    error:{}
                }
            },
            created(){
                this.find(this.$route.params.id);
            },

            methods:{
                find(id){
                    axios.get('/menusV2/'+id)
                        .then(response => {
                        this.loading = false;
                        this.menu = response.data[0];


                        this.fetchMenu(this.menu.orderId);
                        this.fetchSpecifications(this.menu.orderId);
                        });

                    return this.menu;
                },

                fetchMenu(orderId){
                    // console.log(orderId);
                    axios
                        .get('/menusV2/'+orderId+'/menu')
                        .then(response => {
                            this.loading = false;
                            this.items = response.data.items;
                            this.nutritionalValues = response.data.nutritionalValues;
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            this.loading = false;
                            this.error = error.response.data.message || error.message;
                        })
                },

                fetchSpecifications(orderId){
                    axios
                        .get('/menusV2/'+orderId+'/specifications')
                        .then(response => {
                            this.loading = false;
                            this.specifications = response.data;

                            // this.checkSpecifications();
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            this.loading = false;
                            // this.error = error.response.data.message || error.message;
                        })
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

The data is passed down to the child component "Menu" as a prop :

```html
    <template>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <b-table
            striped hover
            :items="menuItems"
            :fields="fields"
            :primary-key="menuItems.pivotId"
        >
        </b-table>
    </div>

</template>

    <script>
        export default {
            name: "Menu",
            props: ['menuItems', 'nutritionalValues'],

            data() {
                return {
                    loading: true,
                    perPage: ['10', '25', '50'],
                    rowSelected: true,
                    fields: [
                        {key: "meal", label: "Meal", sortable: true},
                        {key: "category", label: "Category", sortable: true},
                        {key: "itemName", label: "Name", sortable: true},
                        {key: "noOfServing", label: "Serving", sortable: true},
                        {key: "weight", label: "Weight", sortable: true},
                        {key: "calories", label: "Calories", sortable: true},
                        {key: "carbs", label: "Carbs", sortable: true},
                        {key: "proteins", label: "Proteins", sortable: true},
                        {key: "fats", label: "Fats", sortable: true},
                    ]
                }
            },

            mounted(){
                this.checkSpecifications();
            },

            methods:{
                searchIngredientSpecification(itemId, itemName, specifications){
                    //Checking of the ingredients name
                    for (var i=0; i < specifications.length; i++) {
                        if (specifications[i].itemName === itemName) {
                            console.log("Specification ! "+itemName);
                        }
                    }

                    //Checking of the nutritional properties
                    var ingredientNutritionalProperties = {};

                    axios
                        .get('/menusV2/'+itemId+'/ingredient/nutritionalProperties')
                        .then(response => {
                            ingredientNutritionalProperties = response.data;
                        });
                    console.log("Ingredient : " + itemName);
                    console.log(ingredientNutritionalProperties);
                },

                searchDishSpecification(itemId, itemName, specifications){
                    //Checking of the ingredients name
                    for (var i=0; i < specifications.length; i++) {
                        if (specifications[i].itemName === itemName) {
                            console.log("Specification ! "+itemName);
                        }
                    }

                    //Checking of the nutritional properties
                    var dishNutritionalProperties = {};

                    axios
                        .get('/menusV2/'+itemId+'/dish/nutritionalProperties')
                        .then(response => {
                            dishNutritionalProperties = response.data;
                        });
                    console.log("Dish : " + itemName);
                    console.log(dishNutritionalProperties);

                    var ingredientsDish = {};
                    var ingredientsNutritionalProperties = {};
                    axios
                        .get('/menusV2/'+itemId+'/getIngredients')
                        .then(response => {
                            ingredientsDish = response.data.ingredients;
                            ingredientsNutritionalProperties = response.data.nutritionalProperties;
                        });
                    console.log("Dish : " + itemName);
                    console.log(ingredientsDish);
                    console.log(ingredientsNutritionalProperties);
                },

                checkSpecifications(){
                    console.log("Check Specifications launched !");
                    console.log(this.menuItems);
                    var items = this.menuItems;
                    items.forEach(
                        element => {
                            switch(element.type){
                                case 'Ingredient':
                                    this.searchIngredientSpecification(element.itemId,element.itemName,this.specifications);
                                    break;
                                case 'Dish':
                                    this.searchDishSpecification(element.itemId,element.itemName,this.specifications);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    );
                },
            }
        }
    </script>
```

The problem I have is around the methods in the child component that are fired before the menuItems prop is filled with data from the `axios` request.

I think that a possible fix to this problem would be to use computed properties or watchers but I don't really know if it will help me..

Here is the error that is thrown :

[image]

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because when the `checkSpecifications` method is run on mount, `this.menuItems` is not an array and `forEach` must only be used on arrays.

One option is to add a watcher to `menuItems` and only once it has been filled with a value (making sure it's an array) then run the `checkSpecifications` method.

Alternatively, you could define `menuItems` as an array and provide a default value.

```js
props: {
    menuItems: {
        type: Array,
        default: []
    }, 
    nutritionalValues: {
        type: Array,
        default: []
    }
```

It's always good practice to define the type of your props.